# Do the Onyx Dog's temporary hit points disappear when the party takes a short rest?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, summoning, temporary-hit-points

Do the `Temporary Hit Points`[[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=340)] granted to an `Onyx Dog` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1920)]  disappear when the party takes a short rest?

> **Power (Conjuration)  Daily (Standard Action)**
>   Use this figurine to conjure a black mastiff (see below for statistics). As a free action, you can spend a healing surge when activating this item to give the creature **temporary hit points** equal to your healing surge value.

It looks like they would but ... ???

> **Last until You Rest:** Your temporary hit points last until they’re reduced to 0 by damage or until you
>   take a rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your quotes are valid, and do not disagree with each other. All temporary hit points--including those applied to the Onyx Dog at the time of its summoning--are removed upon resting.

Comment: I would want to add though that if you wish to depending on the DM, you COULD have the conjuration assuming it obeys you not take the rest to keep the THP.  Not everyone has to do a short rest or extended rest, but you'd have to have some pretty interesting reasons for why you wouldn't want the extended rest.